# Why such a context?

Tags: javascript

Why does 7 line return object **window**?

Why not a **sport** object?

```
var sport = {
caption: "2017",
players :  [{"name":"cat"},{"name":"dog"}] ,
show: function() {
  this.players.forEach(function(entry) {
      console.log(entry.name);
      console.log(this);//window
  });
}
}

sport.show();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6qkj2byk/

Comment: Use arrow function.

Comment: The scope of this depends on the execution context and is late-bound. Search SO and the web and you'll find much discussion regarding this.

Comment: "If a thisArg parameter is provided to forEach(), it will be used as callback's this value.  Otherwise, the value undefined will be used as its this value. The this value ultimately observable by callback is determined according to the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: `"use strict";`

Comment: Why would it be the `sport` object and not the `sport.players` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` refers to the scope of the anonymous function in which it resides, which would be window.

```js
var sport = {
  players: [1, 2, 3],
  show: function() {
    this.players.forEach(function(entry) {
      console.log(entry);
      
      // this refers to the scope of the anonymous function, which is window
      console.log(this);
    });
  }
}

//sport.show();


var sport2 = {
  players: [3, 4, 5],
  show: function() {

    // this refers to the object scope in which it resides - 
    // in which case, that would be "sport2"
    var self = this;
    this.players.forEach(function(entry) {
      console.log(entry);

      // self is now synonymous with "this" in the sport2 scope.
      console.log(self);
    });
  }
}

sport2.show();
```

Edit: self could be set inside of the `show` function itself, no need to pass it in the ugly way. Thanks to the comment section for pointing this out.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Because `this` almost *never* refers to a function

Comment: Suggestion: Within the function you can define `var self = this;`

Comment: @Nayuki It is not gonna work either because when is the method is called its context its the windows object

Comment: @Luillyfe he is talking about the show function, not the anonymous function.

Comment: In this case, `this` *would* refer to the anonymous function. `var self = this` outside of the anonymous function would work way better, not sure why I didn't put that in the first place!.

Comment: Updated. Hopefully it's a bit cleaner this way. Thanks for keeping me on track.

Comment: Please review and remove downvotes if the answer is acceptable. I don't want to mislead future SO'ers.